# errorjava.lang.IllegalStateExceptionCan't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

I have created a *Restful service using Hibernate, jersey framework*. Finally I have deployed it to the *tomcat8 server* but the

**problem is:**

service stops working after 2-3 days(Some errors occurred) so i have to restart the Server again to work it properly.Then after 2-3 days same problem happens.

Here is my code where I have closed the session properly:

```
 public Category GetCategory(int id) throws Exception {
    Session session = HibernateSessionManager.getSession();
    Category category = new Category();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
       
        category = (Category) session.load(Category.class, id);
        
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return category;
```

Here is the Hibernate config:

```xml
<property name="c3p0.min_size">20</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">150</property>
    <property name="c3p0.minPoolSize">20</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxPoolSize">150</property>    
    <property name="c3p0.numHelperThreads">10</property>   
        
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">350</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
```

Here is error log:

```
errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
258919314 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] WARN com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@578b3b27 -- an attempt to checkout a resource was interrupted, and the pool is still live: some other thread must have interrupted the Thread attempting checkout!
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1459)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:639)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:549)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)


at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
        at Dao.CaseDb.GetCases(CaseDb.java:34)
        at Model.CaseManager.GetCases(CaseManager.java:23)
        at WebService.CaseService.getCases(CaseService.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)

 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
```

Comment: Are there any other components running in your application like other servlets, WS, ... ? I guess, some other component leaks the datasource

Comment: Hi, i am using this servlet container : <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> and also using javax.ws.rs and JAX-RS

Comment: Your sample code has 2 sessions and 2 transactions started.  Is this really what you are doing or is that just a code sample issue in the question?

Comment: Hi, that is a mistake of copy paste. I am using only one session. I have resolved the issue(Not actual solution) by running cron task which will check tomcat server if server is stopped then it will restart it again :). This is not a permanent solution but i am using it for the time being until i find a new solution.

Comment: Hi @Rakib do you found a Solution for that issue ? I have the same Problem.

Comment: Hi @sulox32, Didn't find an actual solution but created a hack (bash script which runs after 30secs interval to check if the server is running or not)  to resolve it. The bash script will restart the server if found dead.